# Chrome extension TCP socket connection through a proxy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I was hoping google chrome socket connections from a chrome extension would go through the proxy settings of the browser but it does not seem to be the case.

Any idea of how could I automagically connect to a server and let chrome bothering with the proxy ?

Comment: Chrome extensions or Chrome Apps? In the first case, you can use the [`chrome.proxy`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy.html) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't, but we expect that this will be possible using a network proxy API when the bug http://crbug.com/172285 gets implemented.

If you want, star the issue to follow the development.